# How to enable dojox.data.JsonRestStore access struts2's action to retrieve data? I mean how to configure 'target' or others

Tags: dojo

I tend to use dojox.data.JsonRestStore as my grid's store, but I am always failed to access struts2 action, I am unfamiliar in REST, is it only can be used in servlet rather than struts2, etc.

Currently, My project is using struts2 + spring as backend skill and dojo as front-side skill, have you any ways for me to make dojox.data.JsonRestStore access a structs2 action class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to get the data, all you need is an HTTP GET that returns an array of JSON objects. The return value from the action must be a string with something like:

```
[
   {
      "penUser":"Micha Roon",
      "submitTime":"12.03 13:20",
      "state":"Eingang",
      "FormNumber":"001001"
   },
   {
      "penUser":"Micha Roon",
      "submitTime":"12.03 13:20",
      "state":"Eingang",
      "FormNumber":"001001"
   }
]
```

If you want to be able to update objects you have to have a method that reacts to PUT with the same URL as the one you used for GET and if you need to delete, DELETE will be used. The important part is that it must be the same URL.

In order to have JsonRestStore pass the ID in a GET parameter instead of appending it to the URL, you could specify the URL like so:

```
target:"services/jsonrest/formstore?formId="
```

When you call `yourStore.get("123")` the request will try to get `http://yourserver:port/AppContext/services/jsonrest/formstore?formId=123`

REST is nothing more than a convention.

You can use a RESTFull API like jersey.java.net in order to make your life easier and your URL more RESTFull.